# How can I send an email by Java application using GMail, Yahoo, or Hotmail?

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, mail-server

Is it possible to send an email from my Java application using a GMail account?  I have configured my company mail server with Java app to send email, but that's not going to cut it when I distribute the application. Answers with any of using Hotmail, Yahoo or GMail are acceptable.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

First download the [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) and make sure the relevant jar files are in your classpath.

Here's a full working example using GMail.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class Main {

    private static String USER_NAME = "*****";  // GMail user name (just the part before "@gmail.com")
    private static String PASSWORD = "********"; // GMail password
    private static String RECIPIENT = "lizard.bill@myschool.edu";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String from = USER_NAME;
        String pass = PASSWORD;
        String[] to = { RECIPIENT }; // list of recipient email addresses
        String subject = "Java send mail example";
        String body = "Welcome to JavaMail!";

        sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
    }

    private static void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            // To get the array of addresses
            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        }
        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally, you'll want to do more in the `catch` blocks than print the stack trace as I did in the example code above.  (Remove the `catch` blocks to see which method calls from the JavaMail API throw exceptions so you can better see how to properly handle them.)

---

Thanks to [@jodonnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223/jodonnell) and everyone else who answered.  I'm giving him a bounty because his answer led me about 95% of the way to a complete answer.

Comment: the lizard - do we need to forward a port for this???  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); this port has to be opened??

Comment: @varun: That's the port on the outgoing mail server, `smtp.gmail.com`.  See [Configuring other mail clients](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) for details.

Comment: Am I the only one who gets AuthenticationFailedException here 
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); if the true is string. It is fine if it is a boolean.

Comment: this didn't work unless session.getTransport("smtp") is session.getTransport("smtps")

Comment: For SSL gmail connection please use
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); // instead of 587

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working now as of (Sep '13) atleast for gmail. You get 'PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target'. I believe there are some changes at gmail's side to the certificates and protocols.

Comment: @billtheLizard Really not sure what the issue is then. I am getting the same error as stated above and I do find several other posts refer that error. But not able to resolve it yet. I believe there must be some differences depending from which region it is being executed.

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#getdefaultinstance regarding use of Session.getDefaultInstance(properties).   This FAQ recommends using getInstance(..) instead.

Comment: I was unable to access using SMTP gmail with the above and similar codes and was getting `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` and had to explicitly enable "less secure apps" in my gmail settings: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps. Once "less secure apps" was enabled, the code worked

Comment: @BilltheLizard hi.this code works fine.. but how can i attach a image with the mail..? message.setFileName(filename); send the image.. but the image size is reduced to 1kb. so i cannot open the image.plz help.thanks.

Comment: Why use `System.getProperties()` instead of new `Properties()`? Using system properties may have unintended side effects, and in a multi-threaded scenario you may end up sending emails to wrong recipients, etc.
Also, as @Bryan mentions, the JavaMail FAQ recommends using `Session.getInstance(properties)` instead of `Session.getDefaultInstance(properties)`.
In any case your answer helped a lot, so thanks :)

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
Still getting this with your code

Comment: @BilltheLizard THANKS A LOT ...IT helped me in sending email. Just one doubt, I am using local host , my website is not registered as SSL  , can I use SSL port 465 in stead of 587 TLS while sending email in above code?

Comment: Hi @Tom. I don't really know much about this anymore, so I'd recommend you give it a try. That, or ask a separate question and reference this one. Good luck!

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

Comment: Looks like this is not working for me. I get this exception: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Answer (score 115):

Something like this (sounds like you just need to change your SMTP server):

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String from = "user name";
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", "asdfgh");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // 587 is the port number of yahoo mail
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

InternetAddress[] to_address = new InternetAddress[to.length];
int i = 0;
// To get the array of addresses
while (to[i] != null) {
    to_address[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
    i++;
}
System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);
i = 0;
while (to_address[i] != null) {

    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to_address[i]);
    i++;
}
message.setSubject("sending in a group");
message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
// alternately, to send HTML mail:
// message.setContent("<p>Welcome to JavaMail</p>", "text/html");
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.co.in", "user name", "asdfgh");
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

Comment: Is it possible to send the content as html? If I try to write some html code and send it, but on the receive end, the content of the email is only html code.

Comment: To send html body instead of clear text change this line: `message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");` with this line: `message.setContent("<h1>Hello world</h1>", "text/html");`

Comment: This one is missing ("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")

Comment: no need to import some javalibrary? and @Sotomajor, where do we use that missing line?

Comment: @gumuruh in the props. Should have been `props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")`

Answer (score 23):

Other people have good answers above, but I wanted to add a note on my experience here.  I've found that when using Gmail as an outbound SMTP server for my webapp, Gmail only lets me send ~10 or so messages before responding with an anti-spam response that I have to manually step through to re-enable SMTP access.  The emails I was sending were not spam, but were website "welcome" emails when users registered with my system.  So, YMMV, and I wouldn't rely on Gmail for a production webapp.  If you're sending email on a user's behalf, like an installed desktop app (where the user enters their own Gmail credentials), you may be okay.

Also, if you're using Spring, here's a working config to use Gmail for outbound SMTP:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="465"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mail.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mail.password}"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <value>
            mail.debug=true
            mail.smtp.auth=true
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=java.net.SocketFactory
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, for the configuration settings example and for the warning about outbound mail limits.  I've never run into the limit before, but I'm sure other people will find that information useful.

Comment: I'd like to know more about that spam limit... I do have to send several emails, should I split them in groups? wait for a specified amount of time? Anybody knows the details of google mails limitations?

Answer (score 13):

Even though this question is closed, I'd like to post a counter solution, but now using [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org) (Open Source JavaMail smtp wrapper):

```
final Email email = new Email();

String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
Integer port = 587;
String from = "username";
String pass = "password";
String[] to = {"to@gmail.com"};

email.setFromAddress("", from);
email.setSubject("sending in a group");
for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
    email.addRecipient("", to[i], RecipientType.TO);
}
email.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");

new Mailer(host, port, from, pass).sendMail(email);
// you could also still use your mail session instead
new Mailer(session).sendMail(email);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with that code: "Message: Generic error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first" - how do you enable starttls with vesijama?

Comment: I received the "Must issue a STARTTLS command first" error because in the below line I had the isStartTlsEnabled variable as a boolean, instead as a String:
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", isStartTlsEnabled);

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31974869/441662): To use TLS, you can do something like `new Mailer(your login / your session, TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS).sendMail(email);`

Comment: [RecipientType cannot be resolved to a variable](https://i.imgur.com/oHAXBFq.png)...

Answer (score 7):

My complete code as below is working well:

```
package ripon.java.mail;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{    
    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
     String from = "test@gmail.com";
     String pass ="test123";
    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
   String to = "ripon420@yahoo.com";

   String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

   // Get system properties
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();
   // Setup mail server
   properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
   properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

   // Get the default Session object.
   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

   try{
      // Create a default MimeMessage object.
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

      // Set From: header field of the header.
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

      // Set To: header field of the header.
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                               new InternetAddress(to));

      // Set Subject: header field
      message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

      // Now set the actual message
      message.setText("This is actual message");

      // Send message
      Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
      transport.connect(host, from, pass);
      transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
      transport.close();
      System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
   }catch (MessagingException mex) {
      mex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;activation.jar;mail.jar
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Mail
{
    String  d_email = "iamdvr@gmail.com",
            d_password = "****",
            d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            d_port  = "465",
            m_to = "iamdvr@yahoo.com",
            m_subject = "Testing",
            m_text = "Hey, this is the testing email using smtp.gmail.com.";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] to={"XXX@yahoo.com"};
        String[] cc={"XXX@yahoo.com"};
        String[] bcc={"XXX@yahoo.com"};
        //This is for google
        Mail.sendMail("venkatesh@dfdf.com", "password", "smtp.gmail.com", 
                      "465", "true", "true", 
                      true, "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory", "false", 
                      to, cc, bcc, 
                      "hi baba don't send virus mails..", 
                      "This is my style...of reply..If u send virus mails..");
    }

    public synchronized static boolean sendMail(
        String userName, String passWord, String host, 
        String port, String starttls, String auth, 
        boolean debug, String socketFactoryClass, String fallback, 
        String[] to, String[] cc, String[] bcc, 
        String subject, String text) 
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        //Properties props=System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", userName);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        if(!"".equals(port))
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        if(!"".equals(starttls))
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",starttls);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
        if(debug) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        } else {
            props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "false");         
        }
        if(!"".equals(port))
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
        if(!"".equals(socketFactoryClass))
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",socketFactoryClass);
        if(!"".equals(fallback))
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", fallback);

        try
        {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(debug);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(text);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("p_sambasivarao@sutyam.com"));
            for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++) {
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                                 new InternetAddress(to[i]));
            }
            for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++) {
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, 
                                 new InternetAddress(cc[i]));
            }
            for(int i=0;i<bcc.length;i++) {
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, 
                                 new InternetAddress(bcc[i]));
            }
            msg.saveChanges();
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, userName, passWord);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception mex)
        {
            mex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The minimum required:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MessageSender {

    public static void sendHardCoded() throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        String to = "a@a.info";
        final String from = "b@gmail.com";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, "BeNice");
                    }
                });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Hello");
        message.setText("What's up?");

        Transport.send(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: @AlikElizin-kilaka I was trying to use my gmail id for both sender and recipient, found that you also need to set the Allow less secure apps flag to ON in your google account settings, since you are accessing your gmail profile in a less secure way. Then only you can see the email sent from the Java client. Otherwise you get javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException.

Answer (score 2):

The posted code solutions may cause problems when you need to set up multiple SMTP sessions anywhere within the same JVM.

The JavaMail FAQ recommends using

```
Session.getInstance(properties);
```

instead of

```
Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
```

because the getDefault will only use the properties given the first time it is invoked. All later uses of the default instance will ignore property changes.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#getdefaultinstance

Answer (score 2):

Value added:

- **encoding pitfalls** in subject, message and display name
- **only one magic property** is needed for modern java mail library versions
- `Session.getInstance()` recommended over `Session.getDefaultInstance()`
- **attachment** in the same example
- **still works** after [Google turns off less secure apps](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html): Enable 2-factor authentication in your organization -> turn on 2FA -> generate app password.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.activation.DataHandler;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
    import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;
    
    public class Gmailer {
      private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Gmailer.class.getName());
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        send();
      }
    
      public static void send() {
        Transport transport = null;
        try {
          String accountEmail = "account@source.com";
          String accountAppPassword = "";
          String displayName = "Display-Name 東";
          String replyTo = "reply-to@source.com";
    
          String to = "to@target.com";
          String cc = "cc@target.com";
          String bcc = "bcc@target.com";
    
          String subject = "Subject 東";
          String message = "<span style='color: red;'>東</span>";
          String type = "html"; // or "plain"
          String mimeTypeWithEncoding = "text/" + type + "; charset=" + StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
    
          File attachmentFile = new File("Attachment.pdf");
          // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types
          String attachmentMimeType = "application/pdf";
          byte[] bytes = ...; // read file to byte array
    
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();
          properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
          // i found that this is the only property necessary for a modern java mail version
          properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          // https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#getdefaultinstance
          Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
    
          MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    
          // probably best to use the account email address, to avoid landing in spam or blacklists
          // not even sure if the server would accept a differing from address
          InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(accountEmail);
          from.setPersonal(displayName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
          mimeMessage.setFrom(from);
    
          mimeMessage.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(replyTo));
    
          mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
          mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));
          mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(bcc));
    
          mimeMessage.setSubject(subject, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    
          MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    
          MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
          messagePart.setContent(mimeMessage, mimeTypeWithEncoding);
          multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
    
          MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, attachmentMimeType)));
          attachmentPart.setFileName(attachmentFile.getName());
          multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
    
          mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);
    
          transport = session.getTransport();
          transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, accountEmail, accountAppPassword);
          transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
          // I prefer to bubble up exceptions, so the caller has the info that someting went wrong, and gets a chance to handle it.
          // I also prefer not to force the exception in the signature.
          throw e instanceof RuntimeException ? (RuntimeException) e : new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally {
          if(transport != null) {
            try {
              transport.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
              LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "failed to close java mail transport: " + e);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do when i want to send email with attachment, work fine. :)

```
 public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); // smtp port
            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {

                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("username-gmail", "password-gmail");
                }
            };
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username-gmail@gmail.com"));
            msg.setSubject("Try attachment gmail");
            msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("username-gmail@gmail.com"));
            //add atleast simple body
            MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
            body.setText("Try attachment");
            //do attachment
            MimeBodyPart attachMent = new MimeBodyPart();
            FileDataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource(new File("file-sent.txt"));
            attachMent.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
            attachMent.setFileName("file-sent.txt");
            attachMent.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(body);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachMent);
            msg.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (AddressException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy route would be to have the gmail account configured/enabled for POP3 access. This would allow you to send out via normal SMTP through the gmail servers.

Then you'd just send through smtp.gmail.com (on port 587)

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code....

```
package my.test.service;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
        final String SMTP_PORT = "587";
        final String GMAIL_USERNAME = "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
        final String GMAIL_PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxx";

        System.out.println("Process Started");

        Properties prop = System.getProperties();
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", GMAIL_USERNAME);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", GMAIL_PASSWORD);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        System.out.println("Props : " + prop);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(GMAIL_USERNAME,
                        GMAIL_PASSWORD);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Got Session : " + session);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            System.out.println("before sending");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(GMAIL_USERNAME));
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(GMAIL_USERNAME));
            message.setSubject("My First Email Attempt from Java");
            message.setText("Hi, This mail came from Java Application.");
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(GMAIL_USERNAME));
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            System.out.println("Got Transport" + transport);
            transport.connect(SMTP_HOST, GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("message Object : " + message);
            System.out.println("Email Sent Successfully");
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy-to-use class for sending emails with [`Gmail`](https://mail.google.com/). You need to have the [`JavaMail`](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) library [added to your build path](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) or just use [`Maven`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail).

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class GmailSender
{
    private static String protocol = "smtp";

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private Session session;
    private Message message;
    private Multipart multipart;

    public GmailSender()
    {
        this.multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    }

    public void setSender(String username, String password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        this.session = getSession();
        this.message = new MimeMessage(session);
    }

    public void addRecipient(String recipient) throws AddressException, MessagingException
    {
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) throws MessagingException
    {
        message.setSubject(subject);
    }

    public void setBody(String body) throws MessagingException
    {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(body);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);
    }

    public void send() throws MessagingException
    {
        Transport transport = session.getTransport(protocol);
        transport.connect(username, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        transport.close();
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filePath) throws MessagingException
    {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = getFileBodyPart(filePath);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);
    }

    private BodyPart getFileBodyPart(String filePath) throws MessagingException
    {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource(filePath);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filePath);

        return messageBodyPart;
    }

    private Session getSession()
    {
        Properties properties = getMailServerProperties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        return session;
    }

    private Properties getMailServerProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", protocol + ".gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
GmailSender sender = new GmailSender();
sender.setSender("myEmailNameWithout@gmail.com", "mypassword");
sender.addRecipient("recipient@somehost.com");
sender.setSubject("The subject");
sender.setBody("The body");
sender.addAttachment("TestFile.txt");
sender.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use outlook with `Javamail API` then use

```
smtp-mail.outlook.com
```

as a **host** for more and complete working code [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218352/how-to-send-an-email-from-outlook-via-java/41347253#41347253).