# Not able to access Email Box using IMAPS protocol

Tags: java, email, imap

In this i am trying to access Email box using IMAPS protocol.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    props.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

    store.connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", "emailid@domain.com","xxxx");
    Folder elisa = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    System.out.println("No of unread Mail " + elisa.getUnreadMessageCount());
}
```

Error which i am getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at sid.test.email.EmailMain.main(EmailMain.java:21)
```

Comment: Please ask in a better way [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Add a question and a error (if exist).

Comment: Sorry. But do you know the answer.

Comment: How should I know the answer for a question you never asked?
What kind of problem do you have? "Not able" is not realy useful.

Comment: **Invalid username or password**
I would say: "emailid@domain.com" is not a valid username or "xxxx" not the correct password.

Comment: I mean to say, is there anything wrong or missing in code which might be creating problem in accessing the mail box

Comment: Those are just examples

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73580/how-do-i-send-an-smtp-message-from-java

Comment: This the only error i have and i am new to implement java mail api

Comment: The error is quite clear. The account does not exist.

Comment: You added the javax and sun .jars correct?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/73580/ this would not be helping me

Comment: yes i added. But i am able to access the mailbox through internet

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.lifewire.com/outlook-imap-server-settings-1170672
you should use your full **Outlook.com** email address (not an alias).
Are you using the outlook.com email address, not emailid@**domain.com** ?