# Must issue a STARTTLS command first. Sending email with Java and Google Apps

Tags: java, email, google-apps

I am trying to use [Bill the Lizard's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail#47452) to send an email using Google Apps. I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is: 
    javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. f3sm9277120nfh.74

    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:219)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:81)
    at SendMailUsingAuthentication.postMail(SendMailUsingAuthentication.java:81)
    at SendMailUsingAuthentication.main(SendMailUsingAuthentication.java:44)
```

Bill's code contains the next line, which seems related to the error:

```
   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
```

However, it does not help.

These are my import statements:

```
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

Does anyone know about this error?

Answer (score 20):

I found the problem. Previously i was using j2ee.jar to import javax.mail.

I removed j2ee.jar from the classpath and downloaded [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) 1.4.1  and put into my classpath two jars, smtp.jar and mailapi.jar. I use now **smtps** instead **smtp**

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
```

Now Bill the Lizard's code works.

Answer (score 17):

Set the following tags. It will work.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.user","username"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); 
props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");

props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
```

Comment: seems to be sensible, but why do you mess with port 25? it's mostly always blocked out by ISPs and is actually reset back to 465 several lines later...

Answer (score 9):

It is the version of java mail API.
I was facing this issue and I just updated the java mail API to 1.4.3
It works fine for me!

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue when using 1.4.2, updating to 1.4.3 was not a solution. Not sure is a version problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's got to do with using SMTPS instead of SMTP for mail transport. Here's a different version, modeled after the [JavaMail FAQ on accessing Gmail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/FAQ.html#gmail). Note that I have left out all of the finer level exception handling for clarity.

```
private static void send(
        final String username,
        final String password,
        final String recipients,
        final String subject,
        final String body)
        throws Exception
{
    final Session session = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
    final Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    final String senderEmail = username.contains("@") ? username : (username + "@gmail.com");
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail));

    final Address[] recipientAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(recipients);
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipientAddresses);

    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setText(body);

    final Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
    transport.connect(GMAIL_SMTP_HOST, GMAIL_SMTP_PORT, username, password);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, recipientAddresses);
    transport.close();
}
```

Comment: I get the next exception while running your code: Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for smtps

Comment: Seems like the JavaMail resource files are missing or corrupted (see http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Session.html). There are default copies of the files inside mail.jar/META-INF.

Answer (score 2):

This was driving me crazy and so just wanted to add what worked for me. I had to update my version of JavaMail (1.4.5) for this to work - not sure what version was being used before.

Once I updated to new version of JavaMail, the following code worked for me (can uncomment the debug lines to get additional debugging info - port was `587` and host was `smtp.gmail.com`):

```
public void sendMailWithAuth(String host, String user, String password, 
    String port, List<String> toList, String htmlBody, 
        String subject) throws Exception {

    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.user",user); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port); 
    //props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    //session.setDebug(true);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));

    // To get the array of addresses
    for (String to: toList) {
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    }

    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    try {
        transport.connect(host, user, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    } finally {
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

turn on: Allow less secure apps for your gmail account

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps