# Sending email using SMTP

Tags: java, smtp

I am writing a simple Java program to send mail, but am getting errors. Here's the code:

```
package mypackage;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

// Send a simple, single part, text/plain e-mail
public class Sendmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // SUBSTITUTE YOUR EMAIL ADDRESSES HERE!!!
        String to = "atul.krbhatia@gmail.com";
        String from = "atul.krbhatia@gmail.com";
        // SUBSTITUTE YOUR ISP'S MAIL SERVER HERE!!!
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        // Create properties, get Session
        Properties props = new Properties();

        // If using static Transport.send(),
        // need to specify which host to send it to
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        // To see what is going on behind the scene
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

        try {
            // Instantiatee a message
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            System.out.println("in try blk");
            //Set message attributes
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            msg.setSubject("Test E-Mail through Java");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // Set message content
            msg.setText("This is a test of sending a " +
                        "plain text e-mail through Java.\n" +
                    "Here is line 2.");

            //Send the message
            Transport.send(msg);
        }
        catch (MessagingException mex) {
            // Prints all nested (chained) exceptions as well
            System.out.println("in catch block");
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}//End of class
```

Here's the errors:

```
221 2.0.0 closing connection d1sm3094152pbj.24
in catch block
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. d1sm3094152pbj.24
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at mypackage.Sendmail.main(Sendmail.java:48)
```

Comment: plz tell something any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your mail server (google) is requiring a TLS connection, which your code isn't doing.

Comment: and how to do that TLS connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=javamail%20gmail) for "javamail gmail" will yield many example of how to use JavaMail with GMail, like [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/). Google also has a [configuration page](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) listing the connection configuration that you'll need so you can double check the settings.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail only supports SMTP over SSL/TLS.

Add

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

You also need to login to the server:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This URL May help:
http://sbtourist.blogspot.com/2007/10/javamail-and-gmail-its-all-about.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is expecting SSL. There are several other questions on here where people are also trying to send mail through Gmail using Java, I recommend taking a look at them.

[How can I send an email by Java application using GMail, Yahoo, or Hotmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail#47452)

[Must issue a STARTTLS command first. Sending email with Java and Google Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386083/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first-sending-email-with-java-and-google-apps)