# Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: java

I am running this simple example with my `Gmail` account, but its not working and giving the following error:

```
      send failed, exception: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. nv2sm4478384pbb.6
```

Here is my code

```
   public class Email
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

       Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.googlemail.com");
        props.put("mail.from", "myemail@gmail.com");
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom();
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              "myemail@hotmail.com");
            msg.setSubject("JavaMail hello world example");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + mex);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Must issue a STARTTLS command first. nv2sm4478384pbb.6

Comment: You need to add the following line: props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509699/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first

Comment: possible duplicate of [Must issue a STARTTLS command first. Sending email with Java and Google Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386083/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first-sending-email-with-java-and-google-apps)

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774057/how-to-send-emails-via-spring/29676871#29676871

maybe it'll help

Comment: checkout my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774057/how-to-send-emails-via-spring/29676871#29676871

I hope it'll help

Comment: checkout my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774057/how-to-send-emails-via-spring/29676871#29676871

I hope it'll help

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are probably attempting to use Gmail's servers on port 25 to deliver mail to a third party over an unauthenticated connection. Gmail doesn't let you do this, because then *anybody* could use Gmail's servers to send mail to anybody else. This is called an *open relay* and was a common enabler of spam in the early days. Open relays are no longer acceptable on the Internet.

You will need to ask your SMTP client to connect to Gmail using an authenticated connection, probably on [port 587](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Ports).

Comment: Is there any email provider that can accept unauthenticated connection, those days ?

Comment: Now to access mail from Any Java Client you might need to reduce security. Read https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Answer (score 27):

## Adding

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

solved my problem ;)

***My problem was*** :

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u186sm7971862pfu.82 - gsmtp

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.example.sendmail.SendEmailExample2.main(SendEmailExample2.java:53)
```

Comment: That was what I was missing as well.

Answer (score 25):

smtp port and socketFactory has to be change

```
    String to = "reciveremail@xxxx.xxx";
    String subject = "subject"
    String msg ="email text...."
    final String from ="senderemail@gmail.com"
    final  String password ="senderPassword"


    Properties props = new Properties();  
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");     
    props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
       return new PasswordAuthentication(from,password);  
   }  
   });  

   //session.setDebug(true);  
   Transport transport = session.getTransport();  
   InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);  

   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
   message.setSender(addressFrom);  
   message.setSubject(subject);  
   message.setContent(msg, "text/plain");  
   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));  

   transport.connect();  
   Transport.send(message);  
   transport.close();
   }
```

hope it will work for you..

Comment: This message.setSender(addressFrom); should be message.setFrom(addressFrom);

Comment: can we send to mails to webamails using this

Comment: Transport.send(message); should be transport.send(message);

Comment: thanks! this solved my issue!

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same issue while I was building email notification application.  you just need to add one line. Below one saved my day.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. h13-v6sm10627790pgp.13 - gsmtp

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.smruti.email.EmailProject.EmailSend.main(EmailSend.java:99)
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Google now has a feature stating that it won't allow insecure devices to send emails. When I ran my program it came up with the error in the first post. I had to go into my account and allow insecure apps to send emails, which I did by clicking on my account, going into the security tab, and allowing insecure apps to use my gmail.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this error as I was setting the props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", myMailConfig.StartTLS); and here myMailConfig.StartTLS was String and had a true value, So this String literal was the very first cause.
So try to set it (boolean) true like props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true); or if its dynamic then make sure your variable is boolean or if its String then db value should be set as true.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in file application.properties:

`spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true`

That works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    String username = "mail@google.com";
    String password = "some-password";
    String recipient = "myemail@hotmail.com");

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.from", "myemail@gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipient);
    msg.setSubject("JavaMail hello world example");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

    transport.connect(username, password);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.prot", "465");

                        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                                return new PasswordAuthentication("PUT THE MAIL SENDER HERE !", "PUT THE PASSWORD OF THE MAIL SENDER HERE !");
                            }
                        }
                        );
                        try {
                            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("PUT THE MAIL SENDER HERE !"));
                            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("PUT THE MAIL RECEIVER HERE !"));
                            message.setSubject("MAIL SUBJECT !");
                            message.setText("MAIL BODY !");
                            Transport.send(message);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                        }
```

You have to less secure the security of the mail sender. if the problem persist I think It can be caused by the antivirus, try to disable it ..