# Sending an email through Java mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email after getting username, password from user. all the emails are sent to one email address.I added javax.mail.jar and javax.activation.jar files to both build path and lib folder in Eclipse. Here is my code

```
public class Email {
    public String emailTo = "bimlamadhavee@gmail.com";

    public boolean sendMail( String emailFrom, String message, String usernme, String passwrd)
    {

        final String username = usernme;
        final String password = passwrd;
        boolean success = false;

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        Session sess = Session.getInstance(prop, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        Message mssg = new MimeMessage(sess);
        try {
            mssg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username, ""+username));
              mssg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailTo));
                mssg.setSubject("Suggestions");
                mssg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                Transport.send(mssg);
                success = true; 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return success;
    }



}
```

and now I get the following error

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS comma
nd first. w15sm12465435pfa.34 - gsmtp

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1
668)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1207)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:735)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
        at model.Email.sendMail(Email.java:41)
        at control.SendEmail.doPost(SendEmail.java:47)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpo
int.java:2517)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoin
t.java:2506)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Email not sent
```

Do you have any idea for getting this error? thank you in adavance

UPDATED

I edited the above code as follows

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        Session sess = Session.getInstance(prop, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(emailFrom, password);
            }
        });
        Message mssg = new MimeMessage(sess);
        try {
            mssg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(""+emailFrom));
              mssg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailTo));
                mssg.setSubject("Suggestions");
                mssg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                Transport.send(mssg);
                success = true;
```

then I get the following error

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorExc
eption: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBui
lderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1717)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1704)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:1088)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:46
8)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
        at model.Email.sendMail(Email.java:43)
        at control.SendEmail.doPost(SendEmail.java:47)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpo
int.java:2517)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoin
t.java:2506)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.Validator
Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPath
BuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.
java:1478)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.jav
a:212)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:957)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:892)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.
java:1363)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:735)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:110)

        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82
)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1715)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali
d certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.jav
a:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.j
ava:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerIm
pl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustMan
agerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.
java:1460)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
 find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBu
ilder.java:145)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCert
PathBuilder.java:131)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
```

Do you know any reasons?

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509699/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first

Comment: See also the [Gmail instructions in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Comment: You have a typo in the line `prop.put("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "true");`  - there's an extra 's' after 'smtp'.

Comment: Try to use prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true"); instead of prop.put("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "true");

Comment: Can you please check my update and provide me with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the next code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true";
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```