# How To send Email using PHP & WAMP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using this simple code.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: itsthelucifer@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
mail("you@yourdomain.com","test subject","test body",$headers);
```

But even this simple code is not running. It's giving me error as

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
>   command first. q190sm41239770pfb.51 - gsmtp in
>   C:\wamp64\www\phpMailer\mail.php on line 4

FYI: I am working on Netbeans with WAMP server on Windows 10, 64 bit OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must issue a STARTTLS command first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509699/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first)

Comment: try using a class like phpmailer so you can set the login details (SMTPAuth)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't send email with php mail function on windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure your PHP installation has SSL support, check for presence of "openssl" section in the output from `phpinfo()`.

Then set the following settings in your `PHP.ini`:

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://your.mailserver.uri");
ini_set("smtp_port","465"); //Put your server port number
```

In general, do not use PHP's build-in `mail()`. It's a very basic function.
You should use an industrial-strength SMTP library instead if you want to send mail. The build-in `mail()` just does not support TLS (**Transport Layer Security** and its predecessor, Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), both frequently referred to as "SSL", are cryptographic protocols that provide communications security over a computer network), use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or similar package instead.