# Jhipster gmail not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, gmail, jakarta-mail, jhipster

This is my properties part :

```
mail:
        host: smtp.gmail.com
        port: 587
        username: username 
        password: password
        protocol: smtp
        default-encoding: UTF-8
        properties: 
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            starttls.required: true
            ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

But i get this error :

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a
>   STARTTLS command first. q8-v6sm24909647wrj.97 - gsmtp

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509699/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first. try port: 465

Comment: if i only change prot to 465 i get : org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

Comment: Have you tried following the documented tip? https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/011_tip_configuring_email_in_jhipster.html

Comment: well yeah, i did that as you can see above but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following settings. It worked for me.

```
mail:
   host: smtp.gmail.com
   port: 587
   username: username
   password: password
   protocol: smtp
   properties: 
      mail.smtp.auth: true
      mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

For my humble opinion You should do as following:

```
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: <username-email-here>@gmail.com
    password: <email-password-here>
    protocol: smtp
    properties.mail.smtp.auth: true
    properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
```

Comment: @Christian-Vantini: Please add some explanation of your code and how it resolves the problem