# issues while sending email with xampp on localhost

Tags: php, xampp

I am working on a project in which I need to send email. My send mail function is:

```
    ini_set('sendmail_path', "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t");
    ini_set('smtp_server', 'smtp.gmail.com');
    ini_set('smtp_port', 25);
    ini_set('smtp_ssl', 'auto');
    ini_set('error_logfile', 'error.log');
    ini_set('auth_username', 'myemailAddreds@gmail.com');
    ini_set('auth_password', 'mygmail_password');

    //sendmail_from('myemailAddreds@gmail.com');

    $to = 'myemailAddreds@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Hello from XAMPP!';
    $message = 'This is a test';
    $headers = "From: your@email-address.com\r\n";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
       echo "SUCCESS";
    } else {
       echo "ERROR";
    }
```

**But I am getting following error**

*Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\umtab\xampp\htdocs\umtab\email.php on line 23*

Comment: Far better to use PHPMailer then you can connect to the SMTP server direct from PHP rather than adding a layer of complications with the sendmail settings

Comment: Please tell us if our solutions worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error: you get *Failed to connect to mailserver at "**localhost**" port 25*. It's written `localhost`, like the server is not properly set.

I think that `ini_set('smtp_server', 'smtp.gmail.com');` is not working.

Try to use `ini_set('SMTP','smtp.gmail.com');` instead ... that should be the correct way to set the SMTP server!

But anyway, as suggested by @ADyson, it would be better using PHPMailer. You can read the documentation and the usage [right here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Andrea

Comment: Ok thank, I've tried that but still I got this *error*
```//Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. l7sm1379142qtr.87 - gsmtp in C:\umtab\xampp\htdocs\umtab\email.php on line 24
```

Comment: I will try using PHPMailer

Comment: I suggest you to have a look to [**this post here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509699/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first) ... it explains how to figure it out. If my answer helped you, please mark it as the solution :)

Comment: I will try it soon, thanks for your assistance

Comment: Hi there, did you solve the problem? If yes, please mark my answer as solution!