# SMTP ERROR: MAIL FROM command failed: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first when using PHPMailer

Tags: php, server, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm trying to get send an Email from my gmail account with PHPMailer. But when running the php-script on my localhost I get the following error:

SERVER -> CLIENT: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. m12sm23971137wrp.61 - gsmtp.

This is my code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;

$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
$mail->Debugoutput = "html";
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
$mail->Port = '587';
$mail->isHTML();

$mail->Username='myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->Passwort='gmail app-password';
$mail->SetFrom('myemail@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Hello';
$mail->Body='Test';
$mail->addAddress('otheremail@gmail.com');

if($mail->send()){
   echo "sent";
} else {
   echo "not sent".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I already tried a lot but nothing worked. Hope somone can help here :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Must issue a STARTTLS command first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509699/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first)

Comment: You can also check https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fair, your script is doing exactly what you're asking it to, but gmail doesn't like that!

Your problems stem from this line:

```
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
```

This will set `Host` to an IP address, and it has been suggested in the past as a workaround for those using IPv6 (which gmail doesn't like), because it always returns an IPv4 address.

However, it causes another problem: there is no longer a host name to verify a certificate against, and TLS connections fail. So this leads you try to turn off TLS:

```
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
```

Having no TLS means you can't authenticate, so you turn that off:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
```

But gmail (very sensibly) won't let you send without authentication, and so you're stuck.

The solution then is to undo all that, revert to the code as provided in [the gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Answer (score 0):

Try this properties:

```
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
  //  properties.put("mail.debug", "true"); //this turn debug mode on to see errors!
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```