# Java Mail Error In Sending Mails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using a program to send emails. The code works when I use some other mail server. but I need to use my company's email account to send email. And the email account is provided by `gmail` `xxxx@companyname.com`. When I change the `mail` `host` to `stmp.gmail.com, I encounter the following error:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command           first. st6sm11092256pbc.58

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1515)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1054)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:634)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
at Mail.sendMail(Mail.java:48)
at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

The code is as follows

```
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;

public class Email_Autherticator extends Authenticator {
    String username = "xxxx@gmail";
    String password = "xxxxx";

    public Email_Autherticator() {
        super();
    }
    public Email_Autherticator(String user,String pwd){
        super();
        username = user;
        password = pwd;
    }

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
    }
} 


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.SendFailedException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Mail {
    private String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String mail_head_name = "this is head of this mail";
    private String mail_head_value = "this is head of this mail";
    private String mail_to = "xxxx@gmail.com";
    private String mail_from = "xxxx@Comanyname.com";//using gmail server
    private String mail_subject = "this is the subject of this test mail";
    private String mail_body = "this is mail_body of this test mail";
    private String personalName = "xxx";

    public void sendMail() throws SendFailedException{
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            Authenticator auth = new Email_Autherticator();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            System.out.println(props);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,auth);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setContent("Hello","text/plain");
            message.setSubject(mail_subject);
            message.setText(mail_body);
            message.setHeader(mail_head_name, mail_head_value);
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            Address address = new InternetAddress(mail_from,personalName);
            message.setFrom(address);
            Address toaddress = new InternetAddress(mail_to);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,toaddress);
            System.out.println(message);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Send Mail Ok!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mention the SMTP port (`587`)? I can't find in your code.

Comment: "Some error"? That makes it somewhat... difficult to diagnose.

Comment: You might want to look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386083/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first-sending-email-with-java-and-google-apps) and [this link](http://dunithd.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/send-email-using-javamail-api-and-your-gmail-account/) to help you out with your issue

Comment: Google says [JavaMail API – Sending email via Gmail SMTP example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Comment: +1 Been meaning to have a look at this ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost certainly just need to rework your code to add the properties defined in the [JavaMail API - Sending email via Gmail SMTP example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) example.

You can probably get away with setting your `props` to this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", gmailUsername);
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", gmailPassword);
```

As this seems to be for work--if you can--I suggest using Spring. It makes it a lot cleaner and easier to use. I just recently did something similar to [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-mail-spring-gmail-smtp.html) with Spring and Gmail SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define below properties in your java code.

import below package

```java
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
```

and add following to your code:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Use javax.mail.authenticator to authenticate with gmail servers

```java
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
```

Try this should work for you.

If still having issues, refer this error doc: 
https://pepipost.com/tutorials/common-javamail-smtp-errors/

for sending SMTP email using javaMail API

Comment: You should add the important bits to your answer. Show how to define what's needed.