# Send mail on insertion of a record in DB

Tags: java, database, email

I have a table recording trade data . Whenever a record is inserted in this table I would like to send a mail with the details of that record.

Any pointers on how that can be done. I believe working on a trigger that is fired on insert on that table is the way to go but am not sure about what to do further for sending the mail .

Imp to note is that since its a trade table the performance of the query or the database should not be impacted.

Comment: This question is probably DBMS-specific, so - which DBMS? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL or something else?

Comment: Are you using hibernate or any other orm?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an explanation how to send a mail from Java: [How do I send an e-mail in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884943/how-do-i-send-an-e-mail-in-java)

Now, first try to find a method call responsible for saving that object in database. Then add email sending code to the method.

Put that code outside, more specifically after the transaction - you can't rollback a sent email anyway. Just make sure you get a response from database that transaction was successful.

And please note that by sending an email for each new record you may easily bury the email inbox with these messages.

Answer (score 1):

You could make some background task that looks at the table at a regular interval and sends emails for any new records it finds. New records could be detected efficiently by using a serial or a timestamp column.

Often best to run this task from some scheduler that starts it every n minutes.