# Sending Email in GWT using Javamail

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-mail

I am developing a GWT application and I want to send an Email via a Servlet. The application is still running in development mode.

I am trying to use javamail. And I look into [one answer in the StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884943/how-do-i-send-an-e-mail-in-java), but I don't know how to set up the SMTP server. Is that mean I need to do some configuration on the server side of my GWT application? Thanks for anyone helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look up [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) to understand what it is.

Second, you could set up your own SMTP server (for example like [this](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/)), but this has all kinds of security implications. IMHO it's better to use a SMTP server of your email provider. For example [gmail smtp](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) or similar.

Comment: Thank you. I am not going to set my own SMTP server. I will just use GMail SMTP server.