# Anonymous Email from Android

Tags: android, email, send, anonymous

Its been some weeks im looking for it, but just cant find. Does anyone know how can you send anonymous email from a Android?  Im using Intent like in:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
.
.
.
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"sendingToThisEmail@gmail.com"});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "any stuff");
```

But this, or any other thing ive tryed always send the e-mail from the acc you are already logged by default on your Cell phone.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to do this? I am not sure that I want to be receiving your emails, regardless of whether they contain malicious content (links, attachments).

Comment: what actually you are trying to do.

Comment: An app for the non governmental organization I work at. The idea is that anyone can ask for help or delate "bad guys" (drug dealers, rapists or even assassins) using this app w/o being tracked. Im no spamer. Just want to help ppl. Im actually even doing this app for free.

Comment: Then why don't you simply send the information directly to your server without querying the user for his email, therefore he won't be tracked. If you want to receive information anonymously, don't use emails.

Comment: Cant. Our server is not online. Works only via Intranet. I would like some help with the code, not other solutions. Besides, I know you can send info anonymously using email. Did it already. Just want help doing it on Android. Anyone with some answers and not more questions?

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a straightforward way to do this (i.e. with Intents) unless you find some third party library. Also keep in mind that even if you send the email anonymously, the client IP will still be logged in the email.

Something like [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/1975/sending-email-using-smtp-and-java/) might help you get started, but the basic idea is you'll want to find (or setup) an open SMTP server, connect directly with TCP and send messages using SMTP which is a mail protocol, obviously setting some sort of dummy from address.

Comment: Gonna take a look and give it a try. Thanks kabuko.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a solution which takes the user message to a textbox and onSubmit sends the data to the server. At server side user messages are stored in databases where periodically a email sender program checks for the new messages and sends them to respective email ID.

**Pros:-**

1. Since emails are now being sent from one side it will be easier for you to send anonymous emails. i.e. you can have a dummy account like userMessage@yourdomain.com.
2. User IPs wont be tracked by the mail servers since a central server is sending the mails.
3. You can filter the messages which contain spam messages or abusive language by text filtering techniques.
4. You can store the messages for future use. For Pattern Analysis / Statistical Analysis. At the end of the year you will be able to generate reports, If needed in future.

**Cons:-**

1. Mails may not be sent immediately, well that largely depends how often your mail
   sender runs an optimum delay is required.
2. That may require some extra memory space in your database.

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884943/how-do-i-send-an-e-mail-in-java) may be helpful for sending portion, and finally, You are programming for good, keep it up!!!