# how to implements an async email service in spring

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Here is my email service

```
@Service("mailService")
public class EmailService 
{

@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

@Async
public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body) {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(body);
    mailSender.send(message);

}

@Async
public void sendPreConfiguredMail(String to,SimpleMailMessage configuredMessage) {
    SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage(configuredMessage);
    mailMessage.setTo(to);
    mailSender.send(mailMessage);
}
```

}

And I use JavaMailSenderImpl to implement MailSender

```
 <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

to let spring recognize the `@Async`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="executorService" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
    factory-method="newFixedThreadPool">
    <constructor-arg value="10" />
</bean>

<task:executor id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" pool-size="10" />

<task:annotation-driven executor="executorService" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bistyle.lifelog" />
```

But it is said, @Async don't work in service method, right?

What should I do to implement it?

Comment: What make you thing that "But it is said, `@Async` don't work in service method, right?" -- it should work. (If you do not use real AspectJ, then you need to invoke the `@Async`annotated method from an other bean, but this is a different topic)

Comment: Is there any problem in my configure? In my test, browser will wait until the email is sended. And someone else tell me, it is because @Async don't work in service method. What's your opinion?

Comment: I used `@Asyn` in Service methods, and it works. -- "Is there any problem in my configure?" maybe: do you have a second spring configuration file?

Comment: Yes , actually I hava 4 xml files for different config(like spring security). And I use contextConfigLocation to load them.

Comment: Could you please post the one (except them for security),  that are loaded by the SpringContextLoader

Comment: I have the same problem. No errors, no exception, but the mail doesn't arrive. If I remove \@Async, it works. I tried also using the executor directly with a runnable, same problem. I also tried extending JavaMailSenderImpl and using \@Async there, same result. I'm using spring 3.2.3 with JavaMail (mail not mail-api) 1.4.7

Comment: Looking at smtp logs, using async the connection ends after the login (successful)

Comment: Ok, I'm dumb: it doesn't work from tests but works in the application

Comment: AFAIR @Async won't show exceptions. I'm not 100% sure about that, but try to debug the failing code and you might find a helpful exception. BTW. a common pitfall is that Async is no more in a request context… but I don't see any hint for this in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
<bean id="executorService" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
factory-method="newFixedThreadPool">
<constructor-arg value="10" />
</bean>

<task:executor id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" pool-size="10" />

<task:annotation-driven executor="executorService" />
```

WITH

```
<task:executor id="executorService" pool-size="10" />

<task:annotation-driven executor="executorService" />
```

It worked for me pretty well

Answer (score 0):

**[@Async](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html)** works on all **[@Component](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)s**. I also faced the problem as like you. The client was still waiting until end of email sending process (not run with asynchronous). Due to [this](http://www.kgasoft.com/spring-async-method-not-working/) post ,

> ... *that I was calling the method from within the same class. I believe this is related to Spring’s proxying mechanism.*

Now I separated **@Async** methods from the same **@Service** class. That fits my problem.