# Sending email: failed to connect

Tags: java, email, setting

I am using java to send mail.
I want to set the from mail id to xyz@chatmeter.com.
When i am using that for sending mail the following exception is generated..

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:322)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at sendmailtoclient.SendSMTP.sendMail(SendSMTP.java:125)
    at sendmailtoclient.SendSMTP.main(SendSMTP.java:153)
```

I have used the correct password for the mail account.
although it I have used the xyz@gmail.com successfully.
If you have code please post to me.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your credentials are wrong or not accepted by gmail.
You need SMTP server for sending mail. You can use one installed on your own machine
One free one is [here](http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html).
Also check if you have added activation.jar

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this error occurs from not having activation.jar and mail.jar on your classpath. Add them as a maven dependency or add in WEB-INF/lib and it should be fine.