# getting mails via gmail using javamail over SSL and POP3

Tags: exception, ssl, gmail, jakarta-mail

In fact I am trying to get emails through Gmail POP3, I enabled POP3 protocol in gmail but established a session and connection over SSL but I am an exception and unable to figure it out what is the actual matter behind. 
here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:382)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at EmailReciever.getEmail(EmailReciever.java:47)
    at TestEmailReceiver.main(TestEmailReceiver.java:14)
```

and the I connected it as like

```
public void getEmail(String host, String port, final String userName, final String password)
            throws MessagingException, IOException {
        // sets POP3 properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.pop3.com", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.auth", "true");
        // sets POP3S properties
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");      
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
                }
                });
```

please help!

here is my debugging output...

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.required: false
```

Comment: Fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Then post the [session debugging output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469649/sending-email-failed-to-connect

Comment: freak i had seen it, it didnt work in my  case.
@BillShannon yes i applied the fixes but unable to connect.

Comment: So....  Post the debugging output!

Comment: @BillShannon it gives <terminated, exit value: 1>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: That's definitely not the debugging output.  Did you follow my link above?

Comment: @BillShannon this is the debugging output...
**DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.required: false**

Comment: All the debug output won't fit in a comment.  Edit your original question.

Comment: @BillShannon yes edited, but it gives authentication errors too. in fact it throws exception when it tries to connect. although when i telnet "poop.gmail.com"at 995 port it is working fine, it is connecting.

Comment: There should be more debugging output than that.  That debugging output only shows the initialization of the POP3 Store, it doesn't show any connection attempts.  Try using the [JavaMail msgshow.java demo program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples), [as described in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).  Does that connect?  What does the debugging output from that show?