# Whats wrong with this code.Runtime error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am writing this application in eclipse I added all the jar files.I am pasting the code and error.Please let me know what changes I should make to run the application properly.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
public class SendMail
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    SendMail sm=new SendMail();
    try{
     sm.postMail(new String[]{"xyz@yahoo.com"},"hi","hello","abc@gmail.com");
    }
    catch(MessagingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


public void postMail( String recipients[ ], String subject, String message , String from) throws MessagingException
{
    boolean debug = false;

     //Set the host smtp address
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    // create some properties and get the default Session
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    // create a message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // set the from and to address
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

    InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
    {
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
    }
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);


    // Optional : You can also set your custom headers in the Email if you Want
    msg.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");

    // Setting the Subject and Content Type
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
    Transport.send(msg);
}
}
```

**Error:**

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 13sm646598ewy.13

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at SendMail.postMail(SendMail.java:54)
    at SendMail.main(SendMail.java:10)
```

Comment: To send email to Gmail, from Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you also have to set the smtps properties when using smtps.

Simply set the mail properties to include:

```
mail.smtps.host
mail.smtps.auth
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send mail over a connection that expects an encrypted connection (TLS in this case).

This sun forum has several solutions that you might try:
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=617974

Comment: He is, but he's also given the javamail property that should promote the connection to TLS after connecting.

Answer (score -1):

For javamail to GMail SMTP I use the following properties:

```
mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
mail.smtp.port="587"
mail.smtp.auth="true"
mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
```

I wasn't aware that GMail accepted mail on port 25. Perhaps that is the source of your problem.

Obviously you still need to perform authentication, usually via `mail.smtp.user` and `mail.smtp.password` .

Comment: by changing the port I got this error
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at                              
530 5.5.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 i35sm2744098gve.26

Comment: I've ammended my answer, obviously GMail is not an open relay, you do need to perform authentication.