# java mail give java.net.connectexception: connection refused

Tags: java, email, exception

I have the same code on windows and it works well. When i move the code to centos, it gives the exception:
**javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: stmp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**

Could anyone please give me some suggestion about this exception?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you execute a `telnet stmp.gmail.com 587` succesfully?

Comment: looks similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java

Answer (score 5):

You have made a spelling error! It should be "**smtp**.gmail.com" not "**stmp**.gmail.com".

Answer (score 1):

'Connection refused' means one of two things. Either the host:port you specified is incorrect or an intervening firewall isn't playing ball.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just learning how to send a mail through Java, try the following otherwise, you need to set it to your email provider SMTP server, and this SMTP server in turn sends the mail to the appropriate location which is not the case with this code.

**NOTE :**  The code is written in Java Servlet.

---

```
public class MailClient extends HttpServlet
{
  private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator
  {
        private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

        public SMTPAuthenticator(String login, String password)
        {
             authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(login, password);
        }

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
             return authentication;
        }
  }

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
       response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       try
       {
            String from = "xyz.com";
            String to = "abc.com";
            String subject = "Your Subject.";
            String message = "Message Text.";
            String login = "xyz.com";
            String password = "password";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(login, password);

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

           try
           {
                msg.setText(message);
                msg.setSubject(subject);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                new InternetAddress(to));
                Transport.send(msg);
           }
           catch (MessagingException ex)
           {
                Logger.getLogger(MailClient.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       } 
       finally
       {
            out.close();
       }
  } 

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
       processRequest(request, response);
  } 

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException
  {
       processRequest(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public String getServletInfo()
  {
       return "Short description";
  }

}
```