# How to send emails in java

Tags: java, email, jsp, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java)

Need to send e-mails to users.. must have the capability of typing in email id or search using contacts..  sending normal emails by filling up recepient id would also do.. need the jsp codes and library file if used..

Comment: Use the JavaMail API. A good link is at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Comment: Thnx for the tip....solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole API for that, take a look at the documentation for [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).