# apache commons smtp change/remove Message-Id header

Tags: java, smtp, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

I'm using apache commons smtp library to send email using my gmail account. Everything works ok , however the Message-Id header is sent and I'm looking to remove it(not sent it). Digging the net I found something on oracle documentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#msgid

```
class MyMessage extends MimeMessage {
    ...

    protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
    setHeader("Message-ID", "my-message-id");
    }
    ...
}
```

However I don't know how to implement this in apache commons.

Here is my code:

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

basically I need something like `email.setMimeMessage(...)` , but there is not such a method, only `email.getMimeMessage()`

**UPDATE - SOLUTION FOUND**

```
public class MyEmail extends SimpleEmail{

    protected MimeMessage createMimeMessage(Session aSession)
    {
        return new MyMessage(aSession);
    }
}
```

You simply override `createMimeMessage` method and make sure it returns you own `MimeMessage` implementation( in this case `MyMessage`)

Answer (score 3):

Email class has a Factory method to create a customized MimeMessage which can be implemented by a derived class, e.g. to set the message id.

You can extend this method in order to set your message id. The next code creates a htmlEmail message with a customized message-id.

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail()
                    {
                        protected MimeMessage createMimeMessage(Session aSession)
                        {
                            return new MimeMessage(aSession)
                                    {
                                        protected void updateHeaders () throws MessagingException
                                        {                     
                                            super.updateHeaders ();
                                            super.setHeader ("Message-ID", "my-message-id");
                                        }
                                    };
                        }
                    };
```

Answer (score 2):

The likely problem is that 'Email' calls [`saveChanges()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#saveChanges%28%29) on the underlying `MimeMessage` to commit the headers, which calls the `updateHeaders()` method which in turn calls the `updateMessageID()` which will insert a Message-ID header.

Why don't you try sending your e-mail using the java.mail API only, where you have control over the MimeMessage ? The code is even [already available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java)