# JavaMail for Android works for the debug version but not the release version

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, android-build

I am using [javax.mail targeting Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android):

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.7'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.7'
```

Code:

```
try {
    // Create a Properties object
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.domainfoo.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    // Create a Session object
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD);
        }
    });

    // Create a Message object
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Set the sender and recipients
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SENDER_EMAIL));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmails));

    message.setText("some text");
    // Send the email
    Transport.send(message);
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

This works flawlessly and reliably for the debug version of the app but `Transport.send(message)`  throws the following exception for the release version:

```
Exception: smtp
Class: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException
 Stack trace: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
        at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:856)
        at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:772)
        at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:713)
        at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:693)
        at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:750)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:225)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
```

Could anyone offer a tip on the possible causes of this exception? I wonder if this is related to [R8](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code) used to build the release version.

**Update 2023-09-27**

I found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258348/javax-mail-nosuchproviderexception-smtp/33722589#33722589) - adding the following to Proguard file:

```
-keep class javax.mail.** { *; }
-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.** { *; }
```

Comment: This happens if you obfuscate the APK but don't configure Proguard to keep the correct classes.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have just found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33722589/355456 Could you turn your comment into an answer for me to accept? Usually, the compiler complains about missing classes but in this case the compiler was happy. I don't know how one can take a look at the code to conclude some classes need to be kept.

Comment: The only way I know to deal with Proguard and identify needed classes is to run the app until you get an exception and/or the app crashes and then hopefully the exception already contains the information which classes were missing. So actually it is a try-and-error game unless everything works as expected.

Comment: The other R8 related exception is: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.at..." That is a good hint. This "NoSuchProviderException" did lead me in the right direction initially. Perhaps I should treat NoSuchProviderException as no such class from now on.