# Exception in sending email from java via gmail

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp

I am getting the following exception while trying send an email from java via gmail.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
at Mail.Send(Mail.java:75)
at Mail.main(Mail.java:85)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
... 5 more
```

I referred http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_gmail_smtp_server.htm and [Send email using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java/3649148#3649148) but same exception is coming both for SSL and TLS. Any fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable SMTP access in GMAIL, also you need to allow unsecure clients for your account:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/75726

Be aware that the smtp port you want to use is open in your firewall! I suggest to try a connection check from the machine where your code is running with Thunderbird if possible. Then you know if the client is able to connect.

Comment: Concerning the Answer from Pracede: Port 465 is allowed with SSL/TLS by gmail, so this is not the reason why this is not working. But you are right, STARTTLS is the safer way, of course.

Comment: I checked with Thunderbird, but it's also failing to connect to gmail.

Comment: Did you allow unsecure apps here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps? Otherwise Thunderbird will not work. You will only get: Password not accepted in Thunderbird.

Comment: Yes I did but failed to connect.

Comment: Which ports did you try? 25, 465, 587? Are you in a company network? How about firewalls? Please give more information. Otherwise I am wasting my time here.

Comment: I tried all these ports...Yes, I'm in a company network. And I can't change the firewall settings. Is it due to firewall?

Comment: Since there no message from GMAIL that they blocked an unsecure client, they never recieved a request from Thunderbird or our application. I think it a firewall issue. Maybe you can talk to your network administrator or try our application from another network.

Answer (score 0):

After you to enable SMTP access in GMAIL, also you need to allow unsecure clients for your account ( as suggested by LucasF)
Try this configuration :

```
host :smtp.gmail.com
port :587
username :you@gmail.com
password :yourpassword
   JavaMailProperties : 
     mail.transport.protocol : smtp
     mail.smtp.auth : true
     mail.smtp.starttls.enable :true
     mail.debug :true
```

Me I use this configuration with import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage class and it's works.

Comment: @Pracede...Also used 587...but same exception is coming.

Comment: The problem is, that he can't even connect with Thunderbird. There are two possible reasons for this: Ports on the Client or Network are blocked or Gmail does not accept the connection because of an unsecure or blocked client. When Gmail is blocking a client, you will have a email message concerning this issue in your Gmail-Inbox.

Comment: No I don't get any message from gmail