# AuthenticationFailedException error while sending SMTP email

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I try to send SMTP email in java, but I have an error like this and I don't get a mail.
I turn off all firewall and anti-virus.

**The error:**

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14<https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuIW

534-5.7.14 tAxHxbq4WR-vUuV1uOFAvx8NhInfxYTyNHi_8sJ80lX5lBdBla2ROiSKoysMNcFoQ6sGe
534-5.7.14 DUh173tDMolJ64W-Rahx1fhVF_08AvWrphibgQXiyyz5U1FNMMb-eGGJlUIbjyvBgQuZY6

534-5.7.14 tnykIXdVn__mg87aOmtxoss-EiFYeKdvuiBbt5eb9t_NOc97h-PkXOco-9FcYW69Iz9CTu

534-5.7.14 rfyhlo24k9oqIiWtcJwv85oUCO2g> Please log in via your web browser and

534-5.7.14 then try again.

534-5.7.14 Learn more at

534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 pd8sm1306363pdb.93 - gsmtp
```

**Here is my code:**

```
private void btn_mailActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String to = "receive.address@gmail.com";

    String from = "send.address@gmail.com";
    final String username = "send.address";
    final String password = "sendpassword";
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    Properties pro = new Properties();
    pro.put("mail.smtp.host",host);
    pro.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
     pro.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    pro.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
     pro.put("mail.smtp.port","465");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(pro,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
                }
            }

            );
    try 
    {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("test mail");
        message.setText("Hello how are you?");
        Transport.send(message);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Send");

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: And have you looked at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 to find out why its failing?

Comment: Note that your code is full of the [most common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  I don't think that's related to your problem, but you should still clean it up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Login to email from browser and go [this page](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). You will see this;

[image]

Make sure to click "Turn on" and try your code again.

Comment: Thank you. I had to turn it off but it still notice that error.

Comment: You want to turn it on, not off.  Is your application running on the same machine as the browser you're using?

Comment: I try both turn on and turn off. Yes, my application running on same machine as the browser I am using. I think the code is correct, but gmal is not allow send email like this.

Comment: @nistelrooy41001662 i guess this should be accepted as the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After much testing with Gmail, I discovered the issue is that Gmail requires an OAuth sign-in, and not just a password. The solution for this is to use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java). However, this is a very complicated solution that I won't go into too much detail about. If you are interested in this, read the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java).

If you want a simple solution, however, what I did is simply switch to a Yahoo account. Because Yahoo doesn't use the same encryption, it works perfectly. Note: Don't forget to change the SMTP server to 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com', and the port to '25'.

If you want to set it up from scratch, simply follow [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) tutorial to download the [JavaMail API](http://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads/download/javax.mail.jar) and [Java Activation Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-135046.html).

Then you could just copy-and-paste my code, change the top variables, and everything should work! If I missed anything, please let me know! Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class Mailer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String username = "your-email@yahoo.com";
        final String password = "your-password";
        final String recipient = "email-recipient";
        final String subject = "message-subject";
        final String emailmessage = "message";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,    InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(emailmessage);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What you're saying may be correct for specifically Java, but I'm not sure, because on other platforms, Google doesn't require OAuth for using their SMTP.

Comment: Well, if you wish to use Google, supposedly you can [turn on access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps), but I couldn't get it to work for me. That is why I used Yahoo instead. Anyway, I haven't heard of OAuth not being required for certain things. Maybe it's just with Java

Comment: @user4775991 I doubt if the above code snippet works now with Yahoo's double sign on authentication