# Java send email, how to build the whole project

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am trying to get javaMail to help send emails. I referred to examples to here: [Send email using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java)
I created a java project called mailtest, and pasted the code in the link to mailtest/src/SendEmail.java The code copied was changed to:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail extends Object{

public static void main(String [] args)
{

    try{

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"); // for gmail use smtp.gmail.com
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("my_real_yahoo@yahoo.com", "my_real_yahoo_password");
            }
        });

        mailSession.setDebug(true); // Enable the debug mode

        Message msg = new MimeMessage( mailSession );

        //--[ Set the FROM, TO, DATE and SUBJECT fields
        msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( "abc@yahoo.com" ) );
        msg.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("toMyEmailAddr@gmail.com") );
        msg.setSentDate( new Date());
        msg.setSubject( "Hello World!" );

        //--[ Create the body of the mail
        msg.setText( "Hello from my first e-mail sent with JavaMail" );

        //--[ Ask the Transport class to send our mail message
        Transport.send( msg );

    }catch(Exception E){
        System.out.println( "Oops something has gone pearshaped!");
        System.out.println( E );
    }
}
}
```

Then I

```
cd .../mailtest/src/
java SendEmail
```

It gives error of:
Error: Could not find or load main class SendEmail.java

How should I set up the project please? There's no error signs in the file.
Thank you very much.

Comment: r u using any IDE like Eclipse?or u r trying to run it from command prompt?

Comment: @Arin Hi. I wrote it in eclipse. It actually worked by 'build automatically', there was some delay. But I do not understand, why command line does not work. Thanks.

Comment: The code you copied is full of common mistakes.  Read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you haven't compiled the class. You should have a class file named `SendMail.class` in your current working directory given your current command line of `java SendMail`. You compile it using [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). I'd suggest that you take a look at the [Getting Started Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html). You will be better off starting there learning how to manually compile your source before graduating to using Eclipse.

Comment: By the by, it is redundant to say `SendMail extends Object`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, my understanding is that you are using default package.So, 1st go to the `mailtest-->src` folder using cd command.

Type **`cd`** without parameters to display the current drive and directory and check whether you are in right directory(now you should be inside src folder) or not.

Next check where your `SendEmail.class` file is present or not in the same directory (src). If not then execute the javac command

```
javac SendEmail.java
```

Then execute the java command to run your program

```
java SendEmail
```

For more details on [Error: Could not find or load main class in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/04/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-helloworld-java.html) follow this link.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run program from command line. Below command should run as is :

```
java SendEmail
```

Now check where SendEmail.class file is located and run program from there. You can find that file using windows search. 
In case you are using Eclipse, your class file will be in below directory:

```
cd .../mailtest/bin/
```

If that's not your case then, you are missing current directory in classpath.

```
set classpath=%classpath%;.
```