# Can't send SSL mail using company server

Tags: java, email, ssl

I have this code to send mail using SSL and company mail server.

```
public static void Send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String title, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

    // Get a Properties object
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.starttls.enable", "true");  
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "mail.company.au");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.user", username);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.password", password);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.port", "587");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.timeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.connectiontimeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.writetimeout", "5000");


    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);
    session.setDebug(true);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

    if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
    }

    msg.setSubject(title);
    msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

    t.connect("mail.company.au", username, password);
    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    t.close();
}
```

But I get this error can someone help?

> DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response: javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: Don't you need to use `SMTPSSLTransport` instead?

Comment: @negacao that code is from here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/3649148/9130545, and it uses SMTPTransport

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet i found some where some months ago.(I do not remember where exactly).

```
public static void sendMail(String recipient, String subject, String content) {
// config
// Sender's email ID 
String from = "YOUR SENDER ADDRESS HERE";

// Get system properties
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
// Setup mail server
properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "PLACE YOUR SERVER DOMAIN e.g. smtps.example.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.port", "465");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.user", "YOUR USERNAME");
properties.setProperty("mail.password", "YOUR SMTP PASSWORD");
//properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

// Get the default Session object.
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

try{
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

  // Set From: header field of the header.
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

  // Set To: header field of the header.
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
      new InternetAddress(recipient));

  message.setSubject(subject);
  message.setText(content);

  Transport trnsport;
  trnsport = session.getTransport("smtps");
  trnsport.connect(null, properties.getProperty("mail.password"));
  message.saveChanges();
  trnsport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
  trnsport.close();
  System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
}catch (MessagingException mex) {
  mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}