# Receiving an email when a user is created

Tags: javascript, java, maven

Apologies for asking a question here but I am struggling to find any information for this. My website has the ability to create a user but I would like to send the user an email to welcome them to the site and give them information. I was wondering how I would go about this or if there is any tutorials that may help with this.

It is a maven project so I am using java and javascript. Any help would be appreciated and again I apologize for posting the question here I am only new to the scene.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Learn Java mailing

Add required library for mailing in your library folder or add maven dependencies or through gradle built add necessary jar file or any other way....

If you are using maven add required jar files with help of maven

Try following link to learn emailing using java,best for beggining

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/sending-e-mail-with-spring-mvc

Step 2

Refer spring mvc form handling example, I recommend you mkyong. That's better for beginners and professionals

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Step 3

After refer above two examples you must get a idea to develop your task

Means you can integrate that separate modules into single module..

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help. Will try that over the next few days.