# Reminder Email in java?

Tags: java

i want to develop a tool in java for Reminder by Email? 
is there is any way to implement the same in java? please give some sample example or link?

Comment: Do you mean "Reminder email?"

Comment: Can you give more details.  What specific problems are you having?

Comment: i need some sample code for email by java code?

Comment: Check out example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail. Try to use the search function of this site, or even a web search engine before you put up your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JavaMail API:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

Training and example code:

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html