# Gmail Java Library

Tags: java, gmail

Is there any Gmail Java libraries? I've looked at the Java Libraries from Google and GData, without much luck.

I've done a search already, and a lot of libraries I've found seem to be outdated and old.. I was just curious if anyone knew of more up to date libraries?

Comment: java libraries about what? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Erm, JavaMail? Gmail uses standard protocols.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

Comment: are you trying to just send emails via gmail or perhaps take other actions as well

Comment: I want to be able to read the e-mail in the users account, and notify them of new emails that are received

Comment: There is a Google API which will give you access to a users unread messages (if the account is on a Google Apps domain):

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/#gmail_inbox_feed

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is a simple web-interface but the recommended solution is IMAP and SMTP for which you will find dozens of libraries.

Bill's answer here has example of how to use SMTP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452/12943

Answer (score 0):

Now there are Gmail APIs by google. 
Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) for it.