# Gmail SMTP authentication

Tags: java, email

How can I send an email with an attachment using Gmail's servers, but without JavaMail?

I have come across this [code](http://www.java-forums.org/java-net/7247-sending-mail-using-sockets.html).

How to authenticate when using this code (using my gmail account as a sender)? Can this code be edited in a way that subject can be specified? I'm guessing that file.txt acts as an attachment?

EDIT: Here's the code from the link, adapted to my need's (more or less). Only difference is file location, smtp server and "from" and "to" strings.

```
public static void blabla() throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        String msgFile = "C:\\file.txt";
        String from = "myemailaccount@gmail.com";
        String to = "otheremailaccount@gmail.com";
        String mailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        SMTP mail = new SMTP(mailHost);
        if (mail != null) {
            if (mail.send(new FileReader(msgFile), from, to)) {
                System.out.println("Mail sent.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Connect to SMTP server failed!");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }



    static class SMTP {
        private final static int SMTP_PORT = 25;

        InetAddress mailHost;

        InetAddress localhost;

        BufferedReader in;

        PrintWriter out;

        public SMTP(String host) throws UnknownHostException {
            mailHost = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("mailhost = " + mailHost);
            System.out.println("localhost= " + localhost);
            System.out.println("SMTP constructor done\n");
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({"resource", "unused"})
        public boolean send(FileReader msgFileReader, String from, String to)
                throws IOException {
            Socket smtpPipe;
            InputStream inn;
            OutputStream outt;
            BufferedReader msg;
            msg = new BufferedReader(msgFileReader);
            smtpPipe = new Socket(mailHost, SMTP_PORT);
            if (smtpPipe == null) {
                return false;
            }
            inn = smtpPipe.getInputStream();
            outt = smtpPipe.getOutputStream();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inn));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outt), true);
            if (inn == null || outt == null) {
                System.out.println("Failed to open streams to socket.");
                return false;
            }

            String initialID = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(initialID);
            System.out.println("HELO " + localhost.getHostName());
            out.println("HELO " + localhost.getHostName());

            String welcome = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(welcome);
            System.out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");
            out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");

            String senderOK = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(senderOK);
            System.out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
            out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");

            String recipientOK = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(recipientOK);
            System.out.println("DATA");
            out.println("DATA");

            String line;
            while ((line = msg.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(line);
            }

            System.out.println(".");
            out.println(".");

            String acceptedOK = in.readLine();

            System.out.println(acceptedOK);
            System.out.println("QUIT");
            out.println("QUIT");

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: The code I have linked to. I have adapted it to my needs, only SMTP authentication is failing... I can copy it here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tricks with sending email via GMails SMTP service.

Try having a read through

- [Sending email via GMail SMTP](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)
- [How can I send an email by Java application using GMail, Yahoo, or Hotmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail)
- [Sending email using JavaMail API and GMail](http://dunithd.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/send-email-using-javamail-api-and-your-gmail-account/)

Comment: I explicitly said WITHOUT JavaMail.

Comment: Yeah, but he's the clincher, they may provide you with some ideas. My first thought is SSL, the next is TLS. My first tip is, the ports not 25. Take a read, it might just point you in the right direction

Comment: You could also take a look at [SMTP Client with SSL/TLS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98355/SMTP-Client-with-SSL-TLS). It's in C/C++, but the decision might be worth a read