# java email connect method

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the same code that is in here : [How can I send an email by Java application using GMail, Yahoo, or Hotmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail)
for sending an email. Its calling the `transport.connect(...)` and never coming out of that method call. This is happening only when I am in my company network. When I run the same program from a different network its working fine.

I tried to do run it using both wired and wireless connection, but it didn't actually make any difference.

Any reason why it is not coming out of the `transport.connect` method...

Answer (score 1):

Your company network has a firewall that blocks connection to Gmail on the port you have specified in your code.

Comment: can i connect to gmail on a different port

Comment: You have to look on their site and find out which ports they support. I don't know them by heart. But do note that your company's firewall may be a bit more advanced, so maybe it doesn't only block on ports but does packet inspection. Other network ACLs may be in effect. But unless your company is of a certain size, it is unlikely that they have much more than a basic firewall.

Comment: Note that the JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).