# Java to send an email via gmail

Tags: java, gmail

hi all i have just been trying to get some java code to send an email to a user in java via gmail, this is what i have :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class email {

    // Set up the SMTP server.
    java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();

    public void mail() {
        System.out.println("Called mail");
        props.put(
                "mail.smtp.gmail", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
// Construct the message
        String to = "cam01342@myport.ac.uk";
        String from = "richard.dennis@port.ac.uk";
        String subject = "Hello";
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);


        try {
            System.out.println("Setting up the email");
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            System.out.println("here");

            msg.setSubject("Print Job");
            msg.setText("Hi,\n\nHow are you?");

            Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("Sending message"); //does not get to this part
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // Error.
        }
    }
}
```

it  has no errors when run etc, i do not get the sending message in the console, and it is only the Transport.send(msg) where it is getting stuck at what have i done wrong?? are the settings all ok for gmail ?

edit:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class email {

    // Set up the SMTP server.
    java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();

    public void mail() {
        System.out.println("Called mail");
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String from = "------------";
        String pass = "----";

        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
// Construct the message
        String to = "--------";
        String subject = "Hello";
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);


        try {
            System.out.println("Setting up the email");
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            System.out.println("here");

            msg.setSubject("Print Job");
            msg.setText("Hi,\n\nHow are you?");

            Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("Sending message"); //does not get to this part
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // Error.
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT :
Trying the example in one of the links provided to me :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class email {

    // Set up the SMTP server.
    public void mail() throws MessagingException {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String from = "------------";
        String pass = "------";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        String[] to = {"-----------"}; // added this line

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) { // changed from a while loop
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);

        for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) { // changed from a while loop
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }
        message.setSubject("sending in a group");
        message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

and this is throwing up this error :

```
INFO: To
WARNING: #{email.mail()}: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
javax.faces.FacesException: #{email.mail()}: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at richard.fileupload.email.mail(email.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: `mail.smtp.gmail` is not a property that JavaMail recognizes. And theres other issues with your code. For working examples of how to send mail from Java via Gmail servers, see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/).

Comment: I think that you should actually create an instance of transport with the props you create.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an email by Java application using Gmail/ Yahoo/ Hotmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-to-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-hotmail)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use **465** port, and **smtps** (Not smtp) for transport.

A complete workable code from an open source project :

http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock/file/d9290c44d19c/src/org/yccheok/jstock/alert/GoogleMail.java

```
/**
 * Send email using GMail SMTP server.
 *
 * @param username GMail username
 * @param password GMail password
 * @param recipientEmail TO recipient
 * @param ccEmail CC recipient. Can be empty if there is no CC recipient
 * @param title title of the message
 * @param message message to be sent
 * @throws AddressException if the email address parse failed
 * @throws MessagingException if the connection is dead or not in the connected state or if the message is not a MimeMessage
 */
public static void Send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String title, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

    // Get a Properties object
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

    /*
    If set to false, the QUIT command is sent and the connection is immediately closed. If set 
    to true (the default), causes the transport to wait for the response to the QUIT command.

    ref :   http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html
            http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5205249
            smtpsend.java - demo program from javamail
    */
    props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    // -- Create a new message --
    final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username + "@gmail.com"));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

    if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
    }

    msg.setSubject(title);
    msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

    t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());      
    t.close();
}
```

Comment: @Cheok...tried this but having connect exception --

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;

Answer (score 0):

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Try changing above code to:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Where is your `javax.mail.Authenticator();`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with Transport:

```
    final Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, from, pass);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

Comment: @user2065929 Doesn't the code give any exception? Do you use the full email as username (from)?

Comment: Yes i use the full email as the username, and nope no exceptions in the console or anything, have tried a new piece of code from an example but it is throwing up an error

Answer (score 0):

try this code. It is completely Working...

```
package my.test.service;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
        final String SMTP_PORT = "587";
        final String GMAIL_USERNAME = "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
        final String GMAIL_PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxx";

        System.out.println("Process Started");

        Properties prop = System.getProperties();
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", GMAIL_USERNAME);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", GMAIL_PASSWORD);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        System.out.println("Props : " + prop);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(GMAIL_USERNAME,
                        GMAIL_PASSWORD);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Got Session : " + session);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            System.out.println("before sending");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(GMAIL_USERNAME));
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(GMAIL_USERNAME));
            message.setSubject("My First Email Attempt from Java");
            message.setText("Hi, This mail came from Java Application.");
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(GMAIL_USERNAME));
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            System.out.println("Got Transport" + transport);
            transport.connect(SMTP_HOST, GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("message Object : " + message);
            System.out.println("Email Sent Successfully");
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MessageSender {

    public static void sendHardCoded() throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        String to = "a@a.info";
        final String from = "b@gmail.com";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, "BeNice");
                    }
                });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Hello");
        message.setText("What's up?");

        Transport.send(message);
    }

}
```