# Sending Gmail Error

Tags: java, gmail, send

I have a problem with sending emails. I have good SMTP and port but the message can't be sent because of this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
```

Here is the code:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        final String username = "stefanrafaa@gmail.com";
        final String password = "my password";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth.", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        Session session;
        session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("stefanrafa0@gmail.com"));
            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress("stefanrafaa@gmail.com"));
            //subject message
            message.setSubject("Help Needed");
            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("I need help please help me with this program");
            message.setContent("<h:body style=background-color :white;font-family:verdana;color:#0066CC;>"
                    + "If you are seeing this its OK !!!<br/><br/>"
                    + "</body>", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully...");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
            //System.out.println("MessagingException: "+mex.getMessage());
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "[!]Cant connect to the database.");
        }
    }
```

Please reply if you know i asked in daniweb but there is not fast responses ...
Thanks

Comment: Check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-to-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-hotmail)

Comment: i have already cheched that but doesnt work gives me much much errors ...

Comment: You might have a firewall blocking you. Are you in a firewalled network? If you are using Windows, what do you see when you run the command "telnet smtp.gmail.com 465" (without quotes)? Is your Windows Firewall blocking you?

Comment: i think he is not blocking anything but tell me how to check that ?

Comment: @user2133393 The post I linked you is totally correct. Please, read it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

Instead of:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth.", "true");
```

You have a dot at the end of `mail.smtp.auth` and using all the system properties seems like a bad idea.

Here is one example http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: Same error? Different? How about running just `ping smtp.gmail.com` or `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`? Also you have port 587 in the code but 465 in the error. May be you are not running what you think you are running.

Comment: sorry i have maked misstake here what is giving me with port: 587


Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 No SMTP server defined. Use real server address instead of 127.0.0.1 in your account.

Comment: Avast or some other antivirus thing? Disable it and try again.

Comment: uh thanks that's worked but i still dont get the email ... :D
and yeah im using AVAST so how can i fix this of doing this all time ?
EDITED: Email Recived ! :)

Comment: jdb thanks you very much for helped me i have just one last question what to ask them for this problem im sorry for asking this but my English is weak .. :)

Comment: so any ideas how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, which was solve disabling `avast` and made some change at my code, which look like this:

```
public void simpleEmail2(String to, String subject, String message){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message mmessage = new MimeMessage(session);
            mmessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            mmessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
            mmessage.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            mmessage.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(mmessage);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```