# MailConnectException in Java

Tags: java, email, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am try to take unread mails from gmail. There are lots of example code and I used them. The problem is, code doesn't work in every area. For example when I was at home the code works but in working area it is not. I think it is about network settings or different ports etc...

I am using the code that is already implemented in this [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-to-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-hotmail). (First answer)

When I run that script at home it works. In my working are, it doesn't and the error message's is at below.

The question is how can i learn the which port should I use ? or Should I do another thing that I miss ?

Any directions, links or codes are appreciated.

`com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at gmailYeni.SendMail.sendFromGMail(SendMail.java:52)
    at gmailYeni.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:20)`

```
    `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:297)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
... 5 more
```

`

Comment: any proxy in your work area?

Comment: yes, what can i do in this circumstance ?

Comment: You can try the example in oracle forums: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1589188

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are sending mail from gmail. Then please check if your firewall allows access to gmail. If yes, try changing port# from 25 to 465 and try. But it seems an issue that your firewall is blocking access to gmail.

Comment: in my working area, for security there is lots of firewall and something like that. I can access to gmail from browser but cannot access with java code.

Comment: You will unlikely be able to use IMAP and SMTP directly through a highly restrictive corporate network.  If they firewall off the ports, you can't connect, and therefore, you can't use them.   Gmail in a browser does everything over HTTP via their web servers, so is using completely different methods.