# MailConnectException while sending mail using java mail api

Tags: java, web-applications, web, jakarta-mail, registration

Trying to send an email using java mail api. And I keep getting MailConnectException. I have tried multiple ways to solve it without success.

Exception is thrown by this statement

```
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "someone@gmail.com", "myPassword");
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String from = "someone@gmail.com";
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", "myPassword");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    try{
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "someone@hotmail.com");
        message.setSubject("sending in a group");
        message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "someone@gmail.com", "myPassword");//CAUSES EXCEPTION
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    }catch(MessagingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1984)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at com.karmacrafts.util.CustomEmail.main(CustomEmail.java:127)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:301)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1950)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: @Caadi0 Thanks for your comment. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like network problem. Even though it could occur due to variety of reasons, like :-

*"Couldn't connect to host, port" could be caused by wrong host name, wrong port, a blocking firewall (on the server, on gateways, even on your own machine), **network failure**, server downtime, etc.*

Can you connect to the mail server using telnet ?

Also see this FAQ for some mistakes you committed http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes

Read this answer on how to send emails using gmail https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452/3107043

Comment: copy pasted the same code from the gmail link you provided with and I still get the same error.

Comment: You were correct about the cause possibly being wrong port number I changed the port number to 587 and added this statement to my above code and it worked fine.      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Answer (score 1):

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
}
});   
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");  transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

After 8 hours of pain, I've solved this by turning off:

1) my windows firewall

2) my antivirus software

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and the reason is that I opened a vpn. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For me, de-activating firewall and anti-virus did not work.
**I tried the alternate ports given** in the mailtrap's SMTP settings
25 or 465 or 587 or 2525

changing `spring.mail.port` to 2525 in the *applications.properties* file worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Open  /etc/postfix/main.cf

Search /inet_interfaces line and comment localhost, un-comment all:

Restart the SMTP server using terminal command "postfix restart"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZkAD.png)

I will try this from two hour.I find out this issue.It is happened when we not properly config our JavaMailSender class.

From application.properties file the spring boot not pick properties. i debug and attatch the image below.Please check this to clear.

username ,host , port are null;

Make this class EmailConfig

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class EmailConfig {

    @Value("${email.smtp-server}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${email.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${email.username}" )
    private String username;

    @Value("${email.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        log.info("Configuring java email sender :");
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        log.info("port : {}", port);

        log.info("Host : {}", host);
        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);

        mailSender.setUsername(username);
        mailSender.setPassword(password);

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        return mailSender;

    }
}
```

in application.yml file add

```
email:
  smtp-server: smtp.gmail.com
  port : 587
  username: your-email
  password: 'your-app-password'
```