# Sending email from android application

Tags: java, android, email

When the user hits the sign up button, I want a verification email to be sent to the user. But there is something wrong out here. The email is not sent and even if pass the wrong email address and password in GmailSender, the code throws no error at all.

This is code block for the sign up page.

```
package com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.ui;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.LoaderManager;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.Loader;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.GMailSender;
    import com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.R;
    import com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.UserLoginActivity;
    import com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.database.EntryDatabase;
    import com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.database.GroceryContract;
    import com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.sync.request.GroceryRequest;
    import com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.sync.request.HttpRequest;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

    public class UserSignUpFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<HttpURLConnection> {

        public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.ui";

        EditText txtUsername;
        EditText txtPassword;
        EditText txtPasswordRetype;
        EditText txtEmail;
        CheckBox findMe;
        Button btnSignUp;

        String username;
        String password;
        String repassword;
        String email;
        String popupmsg;
        boolean checkedMyNumber;
        boolean checkedShareContact;

        //Get a reference to this fragment
        final UserSignUpFragment thisFragment = this;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            popupmsg = "";
            checkedMyNumber = checkedShareContact = false;

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            //Get the root view
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);

            //Find the edit text views
            txtUsername = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.username_text_view);
            txtPassword = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password_text_view);
            txtPasswordRetype = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password_retype_text_view);
            txtEmail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email_text_view);

            // Allow user to his/her  phone number
            findMe = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_sharing);
            findMe.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                                  @Override
                                                  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                                      checkedMyNumber = !checkedMyNumber;
                                                      if (checkedMyNumber) {
                                                          Log.e("STATUS", "" + checkedMyNumber);
                                                          readMyNumber();
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
            );

            // Allow user to share contact list
            findMe = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_sharing_contacts);
            findMe.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                                  @Override
                                                  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                                      checkedShareContact = !checkedShareContact;
                                                      Log.e("STATUS", "" + checkedShareContact);
                                                  }
                                              }
            );


            //Find the login button
            btnSignUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);

            //Go to the sign up activity
            btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Get the user data
                    username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
                    password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
                    repassword = txtPasswordRetype.getText().toString();
                    email = txtEmail.getText().toString();

                    //validate user input
                    if (validateAllUserInput()) {

                        // create a new user
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        if (checkedShareContact) {
                            readContacts();
                            getLoaderManager().initLoader(GroceryRequest.OPCODE_LIST_CREATE, args, thisFragment).forceLoad();
                        } else {
                            getLoaderManager().initLoader(GroceryRequest.OPCODE_LIST_CREATE, args, thisFragment).forceLoad();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                popupmsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        popupmsg = "";
                    }
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<HttpURLConnection> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

            return GroceryRequest.userCreate(getActivity(),
                    username,
                    password);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<HttpURLConnection> loader, HttpURLConnection data) {

            try {
                //Check if the response code is a success
                int id = data.getResponseCode();
                if (id >= 200 && id < 300) {

                    //Get the user key from the request
                    String userKey = HttpRequest.getContentString(data);

                    Log.d("Hello", "1");
                    //Check if the user exists in the database

                    EntryDatabase<GroceryContract.UserEntry> entryDatabase = GroceryContract.UserEntry.getDatabase();

                    GroceryContract.UserEntry users[] = entryDatabase.query(getActivity(),
                            GroceryContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_KEY + " = ?",
                            new String[]{userKey}, null);

                    Log.d("Hello", "2ss");
                    //Add the user to the database
                    if (users.length == 0) {
                        Log.d("Hello", "3");

                        //Set the values of the user
                        GroceryContract.UserEntry user = new GroceryContract.UserEntry(userKey, username, null);
                        entryDatabase.put(getActivity(), user);
                        Log.d("NewUser", user.userKey);
                    }


                    //Go to the login page after usr is created
                    Intent intent = new Intent(thisFragment.getActivity(), UserLoginActivity.class);
                    String[] user_info = {username, password};
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, user_info);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "User with the given user name already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Login", e.toString());
            }

            //Clean up so the request can be made again
            getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(GroceryRequest.OPCODE_USER_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<HttpURLConnection> loader) {
        }

        public boolean validateAllUserInput() {
            boolean isusernamevaild = validateUserName();
            boolean ispasswordvalid = validatePassword();
            boolean isemailvalid = validateEmail();
            if (isemailvalid && ispasswordvalid && isusernamevaild) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean validateUserName() {
            if (username.length() <= 0) {
                popupmsg += "Please enter a user name.\n";
            } else if (username.length() > 15 || username.length() < 3) {
                popupmsg += "User name must be between 3 to 15 characters.\n";
                txtUsername.setText(null);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public boolean validatePassword() {
            if (password.equals(repassword) && password.length() >= 5) {
                return true;
            } else if (password.length() == 0) {
                popupmsg += "Please enter a password.\n";

            } else if (password.length() < 5) {
                popupmsg += "Please enter a password that is 5 character long.\n";

            } else {
                popupmsg += "Please enter the password again, password mis-match.\n";
            }
            txtPassword.setText(null);
            txtPasswordRetype.setText(null);
            return false;
        }

        public boolean validateEmail() {

            String Expn =
                    "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                            + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

            if (email.length() == 0) {
                popupmsg += "Please enter an email address.\n";
                return false;
            } else if (email.matches(Expn) && email.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("senderemail@gmail.com", "**********");
                    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
                            "This is Body",
                            "senderemail@gmail.com",
                            "receiver@gmail.com");
                    Log.e("Check point", "Get inside the gmail sender");
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                popupmsg += "Please re-enter a valid email address.\n";
                txtEmail.setText(null);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void readMyNumber() {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String number = tm.getLine1Number();
            // I guess a code block must be added to add phoen number to db
            Log.e("My Number", number + "");
        }

        public void readContacts() {
            ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            Log.e("Length", "" + cur.getCount());
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                        // get the phone number
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{id}, null);
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phone = pCur.getString(
                                    pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            // I guess a code block must be added to add phoen number to db

                            Log.e("phone", " " + phone);
                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the GmailSender class.

```
package com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new com.example.grocerycodeu.grocerycloud.JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            Log.e("SEND EMAIL", "IN SEND EMAIL - NO ERROR");
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("FOUND AN ERROR", "IN SEND EMAIL_ GMAIL");
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to send email from your app, rather than initiating it from server side? Storing mail credentials on app is definitely not safe.

Comment: Yeah that's a bad practice but I need this working just for once...could you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems no major issues with your code implementation except for the following line `props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);`, try changing this to `props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", mailhost);`

If you still have issues, then you may implement changes to your code based on the slightly different sample given by Bill the Lizard here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452/3747037.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for you help but changing that made no difference.

Comment: Are you getting any error or warning on logcat? Also did you try the approach I had given as link above?