# Getting error while sending email through Gmail

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

Here I am trying to send mail using gmail but getting error below

```
  javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 
  <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn? 
  sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu7f
  534-5.7.14 Zt- 
  ibTxZf1iCvRrx_zqZ2e0gyU7UDBdKNf3Skj3y1daBQ4lwKDtlbWjuZVSBdqqJvWssPG
  534-5.7.14 
  axQ9afV4DYvgwRA6V94E2JKjGlqxgk8V7wxG9-lgPZoqbzI4rgBIk8SjDYwFt06r7tzWjs

  534-5.7.14 gn4zN1UWm-
 _BhrTGzjP02vV710gi2NHsgX7efxMTbZSowI02n1DL31Qhf_ba5vvtN8mSkI
  534-5.7.14 mutNhiGJSG0_sSI0ZAiblBGGfc1o> Please log in via your web browser and
  534-5.7.14 then try again.
  534-5.7.14  Learn more at
  534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754     vy6sm35491986pac.38 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:648)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:583)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
```

I have been logged-in successfully inside my web browser but getting error while sending through code. I haven't activated 2-step verification.
I am following these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-can-i-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-or-hotmail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do login-to gmail via web browser and click [Clik-this](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).select turn-on button.Once you select you will be able to send mail.

Comment: This is exactly what i was missing. thanx a lot @manikant Gautam

Answer (score 1):

1. JavaMail – GMail via TLS
   Send an Email via Gmail SMTP server using TLS connection.

   ```
   package com.mkyong.common;

   import java.util.Properties;

   import javax.mail.Message;
   import javax.mail.MessagingException;
   import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
   import javax.mail.Session;
   import javax.mail.Transport;
   import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

   public class SendMailTLS {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   final String username = "username@gmail.com";
   final String password = "password";

   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

   Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
     new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
       }
     });

   try {

       Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
       message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
           InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
       message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
       message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
           + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

       Transport.send(message);

       System.out.println("Done");

   } catch (MessagingException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
   ```

   }
   }
2. JavaMail – GMail via SSL
   Send an Email via Gmail SMTP server using SSL connection.

   ```
   package com.mkyong.common;

   import java.util.Properties;
   import javax.mail.Message;
   import javax.mail.MessagingException;
   import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
   import javax.mail.Session;
   import javax.mail.Transport;
   import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

   public class SendMailSSL {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
           "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
       new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
           protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");
           }
       });

   try {

       Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
       message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
               InternetAddress.parse("to@no-spam.com"));
       message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
       message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
               "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

       Transport.send(message);

       System.out.println("Done");

   } catch (MessagingException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
   ```

   }
   }
3. Here is my reference link [enter link and go reference website](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)