# Schedule emails to deliver later in a web application

Tags: java, email, cron

I need my web application to send thousands of per day. Currently, on being triggered by front-end user, i run a for loop in back-end which send mails.

Read this: [How can I send an email by Java application using GMail, Yahoo, or Hotmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-can-i-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-or-hotmail)

Issues:

1. If someone closes the web page after sending request, **request is incomplete**.
2. It takes **long time** to send email and user has to wait.

Ideally, i would like to save the email and content in database from where scheduler picks up the job and send email and notify the user once mail is sent/any issue occurs.

How can i achieve this? Will cron jobs help here? What if application is deployed on windows server? Or shall i write a separate java application to pick up the tasks from database and send mail?  Can i schedule a job in web application?