# Transport.send(msg) not working

Tags: java, jsp, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email from one account to another using javamail. But the code is unable to execute Transport.send(msg); line. What could be the possible reason?
Below is the following jsp code.

```
<%

        String host = "localhost";
        String to = request.getParameter("to");
        String from = request.getParameter("from");
        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        String messageText = request.getParameter("body");
        boolean sessionDebug = false;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.host", host);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);

        try { 
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(messageText);

        Transport.send(msg);

        out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);
        out.println(" from " + from);
        out.println(" using host " + host + ".");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}
    %>
```

Comment: Don't write java code in jsp page

Comment: Where is your smtp port??
anyways put your StackTrace here.

Comment: Test your code with `gmail` server, link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-can-i-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-or-hotmail). and if it is working change the server and port name with whatever you're having.

Answer (score 2):

These are the properties that I usually use

```
properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.user", from);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
properties.put("mail.smtp.localhost", "myHost");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
```

You will notice that I set `mail.smtp.localhost` which needs to be set if the machines hostname is not set up properly e.g. for a VM etc

Answer (score 0):

Try using property `mail.smtp_port` instead of `mail.smtp.port` or:

```
mail.smtp.port=
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
```