# I want the code for sending mail in a javaFx app

Tags: javafx, gmail, sendmail, yahoo

Anyone have **code** for send mail in a **javaFx** app?? I want to send a mail when I click a button after giving email and the messge through javafx GUI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send an email by Java application using GMail, Yahoo, or Hotmail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-can-i-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-or-hotmail)

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a JavaFX question because sending mails is not JavaFX specific. Have a look at [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) to learn how to send mail in any Java program.

Comment: Can u explain that little more please