# Send Output result via gmail

Tags: selenium

Can someone please help me with the commands that send the output result to gmail account ?

I want to send the result "false" via gmail for e.g.

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "commands"? What do you mean by "the output result"?

Comment: Hi Marchel, After I run the test the out put return me answer of true or false - I want the test (commands) send me this results to the mail.

Comment: Still no one know what are the "commands". You didn't even mention what programming language you are using. Just read some tutorial how to send email via smtp in your programming language. Example for java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-can-i-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-or-hotmail