# How to use credentials securely while sending emails with javamail

Tags: java, oauth, gmail, jakarta-mail

I need to send emails through my java web app and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452/8702641) which does the same. However, it requires to enter the password directly to the source code which I do not want to do.

I also want to commit and push the code on github. I could remove my password from the code before commiting but I would have to do that every time I commit.

I looked into Google Gmail API and OAuth for a secure way but couldn't understand their documentation.

Please suggest any secure way to enter password? or a quickstart to use Gmail API for sending emails through a web app would also be appreciated.

Comment: make the password configurable?

Comment: Read the pwd from a configurable place, like @Pali suggested, and store it there in encrypted fashion