# Is there any way to send an email from our application on a specific date and time?

Tags: java, android

As a beginner in android, I am developing a Tasks manager app.

There is an option in the app, where the app **can send the user a reminder by email on the date and time he wants**, is there any way to do it?

The email's body will contain the Task's title and other info about it.

Comment: I believe that is a task for a backend mail server to do. Your app shouldn't handle that logic. Instead you should have a server where you can save your reminder data and program it to send an email on the date and time.

Comment: I am saving the reminder data in Firebase. But how can I program it to send the email on a specific date and time? That's exactly the problem I am facing.

Comment: Since you using firebase why don't you try the Cloud Scheduler you basically need something similar to a cron job or task scheduler. Also https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler Android has JobScheduler class but i would not recommend having your app trigger the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Mail API:
Here is an example for sending an email with GMail.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452/13912132

You will need the JAR-Files (Website: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) 
Or with maven:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```