# How do I send a email with java?

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send a email using java mail. But when I run the code bellow I get a ton of errors. Can you explain to me why the code is not working. So what I am trying to do is to send a email using a java. If there is any other way can you please tell me bellow. My guess is something is wrong about the smpt server. I am new to stack overflow so please forgive me if I have not wrote the question correctly.

***Edit: I now understand what is wrong I do not have a SMPT server running on my local host. Can someone explain how to create a SMPT server for free.***

**These are the errors I get...**

```java
/home/theprogrmmer/.jdks/openjdk-15.0.1/bin/java -javaagent:/home/theprogrmmer/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.8194.7/lib/idea_rt.jar=44243:/home/theprogrmmer/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/202.8194.7/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/out/production/practice 1:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.ejb.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.jms.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.annotation.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.persistence.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.resource.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.transaction.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.servlet.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/src/com/company/mail.jar:/home/theprogrmmer/IdeaProjects/practice 1/src/com/company/jaf-1.0.2/activation.jar com.company.SendEmail
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.company.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:574)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:563)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:597)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 7 more
```

**This is my java code....**

```java
package com.company;

// File Name SendEmail.java

import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "web@gmail.com";

        // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
        String host = "localhost";

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("This is actual message");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow looks like SMTP server is not  running in your localhost first you will need to do that. There are MailHog, MailCatcher and products like that to get you started if you are not sure. You can Google it up.

Comment: Take a look on this link, I hope that will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-can-i-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-or-hotmail

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Setup a Local Only SMTP Email Server (Linux, Unix, Mac)**

**1 - Point localhost.com to your machine**

Most of programs will not accept an email using just @localhost as domain. So, edit /etc/hosts file to make the domain localhost.com point to your machine, including this content to the file:

127.0.0.1 localhost.com

**2 - Install Postfix**

Fedora/CentOS/RHEL: sudo yum install postfix

Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install postfix

MacOSX: Postfix is already installed by default.

**3 - Configure Postfix to Local only**

```
During postfix install process, the configure text dialog will display five options:

General type of mail configuration: 

No configuration
Internet Site
Internet with smarthost
Satellite system
Local only

Select "Local Only".

For the domain name, use the default suggested and finish the install.
```

**4 - Configure a Catch-all Address**

Enabling this, you can use any email address ending with "@localhost" or "@localhost.com".

Example: here, my unique account is rael@localhost.com. But while testing systems, I can use any address like joe@localhost.com, foo@localhost.com, etc, because all will be redirected to rael@localhost.com

```
If not exists, create file /etc/postfix/virtual: sudo nano /etc/postfix/virtual
Add the following 2 lines content, replacing <your-user> with your Unix user account:
```

@localhost 
@localhost.com

```
Save and close the file.
Configure postifx to read this file:
    Open /etc/postfix/main.cf: sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
    And check if this line is enabled, or add it if not exists: virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
Activate it: sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
Reload postfix: sudo systemctl restart postfix
If you're under non systemd distro, like Ubuntu 14.04, service restart command probably is: sudo service postfix reload
```

**5 - Install Thunderbird**

Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install thunderbird

**6 - Configure Thunderbird**

```
Skip the welcome screen (click in the button to use existing accounts);
Click in the Settings button at top right (similar to Chrome settings) then click on Preferences > Account Settings
Under Account Actions choose "Add Other Account"
Select "Unix Mailspool (Movemail)"
Your account will be <your-user>@localhost (of course, replace <your-user> with your user account). Don't use <your-user>@(none), use <your-user>@localhost
Ingoing and Outgoing server will be: localhost
Restart (close and reopen) Thunderbird.
```

**7 - Start your Mail Spool file**

```
This step have two purposes: test your install and stop the Unable to locate mail spool file. message.
Using Thunderbird, send new email to <your-user>@localhost, replacing <your-user> with your user account
Click on "Get Mail"
Test catch-all: send new email to averagejoe@localhost
Click on "Get Mail" and you'll see the message at Inbox.
```